# Instant reboot on Windows: how to help analyzing the issue for Microsoft?

Tags: windows, reboot, windows-10-preview, visual-studio-2012

So, I accidentally found a critical issue on Windows: the ability to instantly reboot the system from an application. I already reported it on connect.microsoft.com [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1228408/instant-reboot-of-computer-when-running-wp7-1-emulator-from-vs2012-on-windows-10-builds-10049-10074) and on Windows Feedback.

But:

- it is only for a newer OS (Windows 10) that is not yet supported by connect.microsoft.com
- the issue happens with an old MS app (VS2012 Express) that is no more supported by connect.microsoft.com

So I was wondering if I could help the Microsoft team by finding and pinpointing the application command/instruction that is responsible for the OS instant reboot. Is there a way to debug the issue myself? Maybe some memory dumps or crash logs or debug tools somewhere?

I know that analyzing an instant reboot of the OS is probably tricky, but I really don't want this critical issue to be still present when Windows 10 will be officially released.

Comment: That actually sounds like a Hyper-V glitch triggering a bugcheck, likely 0x20001 HYPERVISOR_ERROR. (The Windows Phone emulator uses Hyper-V.) Try disabling automatic restart on system failure.

Comment: look in eventlog for details (STOP code)

Comment: Automatic restart on system failure is already disabled for me. This instant reboot is more powerful than we think it is. Will now check for eventlog.